# Finding a Formal limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate with the definition ($\varepsilon$, $\delta$)
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+n-1}{4n^2
> +1}
> $$

I couldn't solve this problem with the epsilon method

I know that the limit is 1/4 but how can I reach it from the formal definition?

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the problem,your given link isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\left|\frac{n^2 + n - 1}{4n^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{4}\right| = \frac{|4n - 5|}{4(4n^2 + 1)} \le \frac{|4n - 5|}{16n^2} \le \frac{1}{4n} + \frac{5}{n^2}.$$
Try making $N$ large enough so that each term less than $\varepsilon / 2$ for $n \ge N$.

Comment: thanks a lot you have helped me

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$\mid \frac{n^2+n-1}{4n^2+1}-\frac{1}{4} \mid =\mid \frac{1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2} }{4+\frac{1}{n^2}}-\frac{1}{4} \mid$

and after you can imitate the prove of the arithemetic low for limit to find the limit

Comment: i couldn't go on after this step

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\varepsilon >0$ is given we wish to show that

$$\left|\frac{n^2+n-1}{4n^2+1}-\frac14\right|<\left|\frac{n^2+n-1}{4n^2}-\frac {n^2}{4n^2}\right|=\left|\frac{n-1}{4n^2}\right|<\frac{1}{4n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}<\varepsilon$$

Then make $\frac{1}{4n}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4n^2}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ so that the above inequality holds if we choose $N> \operatorname{max}\{\frac{1}{2\varepsilon},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}\}$.

Comment: how did you delete the +1 from the denominator ??

Comment: @YyyUuu: $4n^2+1 > 4n^2 \implies \dfrac{1}{4n^2+1} < \dfrac{1}{4n^2}$.